# CSS3 Dropdown Menu Links not working in iOS

Tags: html, ios, css

I have an issue with iOS not loading the dropdown menu links, it works fine in others, only iOS.

Live Site: http://sandbox.myramani.com/espace/

Basically when you view it via any iOS browser, the navigation dropdown links do not link to the interior pages, instead it just refreshes the homepage. Can anyone help me figure out why this is occurring?

CSS:

```
#nav ul li ul.dd {
box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
position:absolute;
z-index:99;
top:60px;
left:0px;
margin-left:0px;
width:220px;
background:#fff;
display:none;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
padding-bottom:10px;}

#nav ul li:hover ul.dd, #nav ul li:focus ul.dd {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: There's no hover on ios, but when you tap that dropdown and then tap a page under the drop down it goes to the home page? I would think, if this is the case, it's going to the home page because it's going to the link in the slider, that's a z-index issue between the PARENT of the navigation and the slider, maybe.

Comment: You're right but then also on the interior page the same issue applies. The dropdown menu links just can't be clicked... I am thinking that :hover is the issue and needs to be replaced with :focus? But I can't get it to work.

Comment: I wish I had some idea, I haven't used :hover in a couple years now.

Comment: I know what it is. Are you using display:none in the nav and then display:block?

Comment: If so this is a common issue. Post your navigation css only or at least the default and then the :hover state and I'll post the fix

Comment: Or are you using visibility:hidden?

Comment: I'm using display: none and then display: block, let me post my nav CSS in the above post.

Comment: CSS is now posted, please let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason for:

```
onclick="return true"
```

on the ? Could be the issue. I don't see the need for an JS on those.

Comment: I'm not too sure, I tried to implement that but I will remove it to see if it works, thanks!

Comment: Looking at this in Safari inspector and it seems as though some of the <li> tags in the nav may have some broken code. Specifically class. Take a look at this http://awesomescreenshot.com/0123ypfs4a

Try retyping the quotes. Might have pasted in some bad characters.

Answer (score 0):

IOS ignores any links that have display:none OR visibility:hidden -- even if the :hover shows it. I can't remember the specifics.

Now I have the quote from Apple:

> "if the contents of the page changes on the
>   mousemove event, no subsequent events in the sequence are sent."

Replace with the following:

```
       #nav ul li ul.dd {
          box-sizing:border-box;
          -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
          position:absolute;
          z-index:99;
          top:60px;
          left:0px;
          margin-left:0px;
          background:#fff;
          opacity:0; /* added */
          width:0px;/* added */
          height:0px;/* added */
          overflow:hidden;/* added */
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
          padding-bottom:10px;
      }

        #nav ul li:hover ul.dd, #nav ul li:focus ul.dd {
           opacity:1;
           width:220px;
           height:auto;
           overflow:visible;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't seem to work! I tried the interior pages as well but the drop-down links did not seem to work whenever I tried tapping them with my finger on the iPhone 4S or clicking (I'm using BrowserStack to test for iPads etc.) I'll take a deeper look but thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: The demo site is using the display:none and so I can't test it on an ipad

Comment: Thanks for all your help Christina but this seems to be a problem that I can't solve. I've removed display: none and used the new styles as per your edit but even still the menu won't work.

Comment: Try one more thing. Make the links <a href="... display:block, they are inline now. And put a position:relative on them.